# lightbox not showing different images

Tags: javascript, html, gallery, lightbox

I found a lightbox online and copied it into my code.
the first image works perfectly, onclick to show, then click again to close.
but when you click on the second picture it shows the first one again, eventhough i replaced all the sources with another picture. what am i doing wrong? And be gentle, i'm new to all this

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"><img id="gallery1" src="gallery1.jpg"></img></a></p>
        <div id="light" class="white_content1"></a> <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"><img id="gallery1lb" src="gallery1.jpg"></img></a></div>
        <div id="fade" class="black_overlay1">
        </div>

        <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"><img id="gallery2" src="gallery2.jpg"></img></a>
        <div id="light" class="white_content2"></a> <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"><img id="gallery2lb" src="gallery2.jpg"></img></a></div>
        <div id="fade" class="black_overlay2"> 
        </div>
```

Comment: Because you have duplicate id `light`, and `document.getElementById`  will always return the first one. Usually we give similar elements same `class`, and give them different `id`s, it seems you just do it reversely. You should change the second img's `id` to something like `light2` and `document.getElementById('light2').style.display='block';` in second `<a>`.

Comment: It works man, thanks alot.